# How to get current user id, if i inherits from IdentityUser?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I add some fields in IdentityUser like a

```
public class CustomUser: IdentityUser
    {
        public string field1 {get;set;}
        public string field2 {get;set;}
    }
```

after migration, on Sql Management studio i had all data, which i added with `.OnModelCreating`

But, How i can get any field from current authorized CustomUser (like a ID)

I try use

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

CustomUser.Identity.GetUserId()
```

But it doesnt work.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In ASP.Net Core ,if your Controller inherits the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller`, you could get the `IClaimsPrincipal` from the User property and get the actual "Id" of the user,

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = this.User;
var currentUserID = currentUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

You can also get the data of all fields(include Id) from the database's User entity:

1.DI UserManager

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

2.Use it like below:

```
var id = userManager.GetUserId(User); // get user Id
var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User); // get user's all data
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to first save user data in claims and then get authorized user data.

Add Claims

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()));
```

Get Claims

```
var userId = (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

Display current application user name in view:

```
@User.Identity?.Name`
```

Display current Windows user name in view:

```
@Environment.UserName
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).